# I want to stop chatter emails when I create ContentDocumentLink

Tags: chatter-file, contentdocument

I'm uploading multiple files via the SOAP API in a nightly process.  Part of that is assigning permissions to the files. I'm using ContentDocumentList to allow a user to see a document.  When creating ContentDocumentList object, an e-mail gets sent.  If  a user has access to 50 new documents, he would get 50 e-mails messages.

I want to suppress the automatic e-mail messages, then I'll send one e-mail per person with a list of files that were updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used the following User object settings to turn off Chatter's emails.  There are several of these kinds of fields in the User object....

u.UserPreferencesDisableAllFeedsEmail=true;
u.UserPreferencesDisableFileShareNotificationsForApi=true;